# Computing cross-category sales from user transaction data - For users who have done more than 1 transaction

Tags: sql, vertica

[image]Hi,

Input Data

I'm having a daily user level transaction_data and I want to compute monthly cross-category sales - aggregation for users who have bought from more than 1 category only.

Output -[image: Output]

Can someone please suggest how to go about this in sql?

Comment: Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, Apologies for not being able to share relevant data due to privacy concerns. If you could be able to share an approach, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: We are not interested in actual data. Please read the link in my previous comment. It will help in formulating the question in a better manner.

Comment: @dany99 . . . I removed the MySQL tag, assuming that Vertica is more intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . this seems to do what you describe:

```
select date_trunc('month', day), category,
       sum(transaction_amount), count(distinct user_id)
from (select d.*,
             min(category) over (partition by userid, date_trunc('month', day)) as min_category,
             max(category) over (partition by userid, date_trunc('month', day)) as max_category
      from daily d
     ) d
where min_category <> max_category -- at least two categories
group by date_trunc('month', day), category;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Getting an exception for where clause here.ERROR: Aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause

Comment: @dany99 . . . I fixed the typo.